# Relation between pagesize and pagefault

Tags: operating-system, page-fault

I studied from book william stalling ,it was written there if we increase the size of page then pagefault first increases and then when pagesize become size of process then pagefault decreases.
I am not able to understand why pagefault increases as if i increase the pagesize,any one plz explain the reason.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**pages** are fixed size 'chunks' which are formed by dividing logical memory.if we increase the **page size** the number of **pages** will decrease `( consider an example for that matter , if you have to divide a large piece of bread among few people then you have to make sure that pieces are distributed to all now if you cut it into large chunks the number of pieces will not be sufficient enough to feed all people so some will remain hungry)`.similarly if number of **pages** decrease the CPU will have a very few addresses to refer to and thus increase the number of **page faults**.now if page size becomes the size of the process then there will almost as many number of **pages** as the number of **processes** so CPU will refer to it with no **pagefaults**.

Comment: if like the answer then please do not forget to accept it .thanks!!